# Program prints the else condition even when the if statements are true in Python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I'd like to convert my Celsius temp to fahrenhite and vice versa. This is the code I've given:

temperature=int(input('what is the temperature? '))

type=input('is it in celsius or fahrenheit: ')

if temperature == 'celsius':

```
converted_temp = (temperature*9/5)+32 

print("The converted temp in fahrenheitis: ",converted_temp)
```

elif temperature == 'fahrenheit':

```
converted_temp = (temperature-32)*5/9 

print('The converted temperature in celsius is:',converted_temp)
```

else:

```
print("SORRY! Enter either Celsius or Fahrenheit")
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use `type` word, it is registered as a special word in python

```py
temperature_type = input('is it in celsius or fahrenheit: ')
temperature_value = int(input('what is the temperature? '))

if temperature_type == 'celsius': 
    converted_temp = (temperature_value * 9 / 5) + 32 
    print("The converted temp in fahrenheitis: ", converted_temp) 
elif temperature_type == 'fahrenheit': 
    converted_temp = (temperature_value - 32) * 5 / 9 
    print('The converted temperature in celsius is:', converted_temp) 
else: 
    print("SORRY! Enter either Celsius or Fahrenheit")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood it now. But what do you mean by you don't see any question. I posted the question in the title . Is it now where you post it ? I'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: @Juggle sorry, didn't understand that this is a question :) Have a nice day